# What screenshots are actually required for submission?

Tags: ios-appstore, screen-capture

I am confused. The apple guidelines say things like:

> If your app indicates that it is optimized for the iPhone 6, at least one 4.7-inch screenshot is required. Up to four additional screenshots can be uploaded. You can rearrange the screenshots when you create or edit the iTunes Connect record.

And

> If your app indicates that it is optimized for the iPhone 6 Plus, at
>   least one 5.5-inch screenshot is required. Up to four additional
>   screenshots can be uploaded. You can rearrange the screenshots when
>   you create or edit the iTunes Connect record.

I am about to submit an iPhone game, in my .xcodeproj file I have `Devices` set to `iPhone`, so it is supposed to run on iPhone, and iPad in compatibility mode.

What does "optimized for" mean? Where do I set what my game is optimized for? Do I need to provide iPhone 6 and 6 Plus screenshots?

What about iPad screenshots? The compatibility mode screenshots don't look great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you optimized you app to iPhone 6 and 6 Plus you have to add new image and icon sizes in your assets. If you select `Images.xcassets` in your project and then select your AppIcon and hit <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> you must see something like that:

[image]

If you have selected iOS 8.0 and Later Sized you will have to provide screenshots for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, in other case, it won't be necessary.

Comment: what about iPad sizes?

Comment: If you run in compatibility mode, you won't be able to update screenshots for it as the app is "only" for iPhone.

Comment: @jherran what if app does not support native resolution for iPhone 6 and 6 plus and still we provide screen shots for 4.7 and 5.5 inch display in zoom mode. Will there be any issue in such case.

Comment: @iLearner nop. Just people on 4.7 and 5.5 devices will able to see those zoomed screenshot.

Comment: i unchecked 8.0, but the when you test the app, the 4 inch views do not get stretched to 5.5 inch